# Inserting new Core Data object to to-many NSOrderedSet ignores index

Tags: ios, core-data, nsorderedset

I'm getting a weird behaviour when inserting a new Core Data entity (EntityB) into the NSOrderedSet relationship property of another entity (EntityA); the `index` is ignored and the object is always inserted at the end of the ordered set.

The object being inserted is a copy of an existing object, using a different parent entity created using a custom copy initializer:

```
// EntityA
@NSManaged var entityBs: NSOrderedSet    // to-many relationship


// EntityB
@NSManaged var entityA: EntityA?


// Inserting EntityB copy into EntityA 
let entityBCopy = EntityB(entityB: entityBOriginal, newParent: entityA)
entityA.insertIntoEntityBs(entityBCopy, at: index)
```

`entityBs` before the insert:

```
entity0
entity1
entity2
entity3
entity4
```

`entityBs` after inserting `newEntity2` at index 2:

```
entity0
entity1
entity2
entity3
entity4
newEntity2    < inserted at the end of ordered set, not at index 2
```

I've confirmed that `index` is within the bounds of `entityBs`' contents.

EntityA uses Core Data Generated Accessors, but I also tried inserting the object manually via the key value coding method - the same issue occurs. This makes me wonder if it's a problem on NSOrderedSet, rather than being a Core Data problem.

I have no ideas why this is happening, so any info would be welcome!

Comment: Please show code for `insertIntoEntityBs` method.

Comment: @MikeTaverne `insertIntoEntityBs` is generated automatically by Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the initialization of `entityBCopy`, specifically with the `newParent` param. Initializing `EntityB` with a parent relationship, then immediately inserting the `EntityB` instance into the same parent is redundant. The Core Data generated `insert` method should handle setting the parent property on `entityBCopy`, assuming everything is set up correctly in the model.

Therefore, removing the `newParent` parameter from the initializer should result in inserting at the correct index:

```
// Inserting EntityB copy into EntityA 
let entityBCopy = EntityB(entityB: entityBOriginal)
entityA.insertIntoEntityBs(entityBCopy, at: index)
```

Happy coding!

Comment: The problem with this is the whole point of copying is to give the copy a different parent (as it is intended that the source EntityA is not mutated).

Comment: Given my change of removing the 2nd argument of the initializer, `entityBCopy` will have a nil parent after initialization. Then, assuming `entityA` is intended to be the new parent, calling `entityA.insertIntoEntityBs(entityBCopy, at: index)` will successfully establish `entityA` as the parent of `entityBCopy`.

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on here. Because `insertIntoEntityBs()` is being called on `entityA`, that entity instance is populated automatically.